# How do I change my "Vendor Class ID"?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, dhcp

My device's "Vendor Class ID" is `dhcpcd-5.2.10:Linux-3.0.8-gb55e9ac:armv7l:herring`.  I don't know what Vendor Class ID is, but how do I change it to something else?

My question is not related to programming.

Comment: VCID is normally a device value used by PC-side drivers and AFAIK not changeable.  Can you elaborate on your problem -- what you're trying to accomplish by this?  We may still be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

The Vendor ID that @MatthewRead mention is used for the PC drivers. What you are talking about is a DHCP Vendor Class Identifier.

From [Microsoft Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc977408.aspx) (not android specific, but has the same meaning)

> Can be used by DHCP clients to identify their vendor type and configuration. When using this option, vendors can define their own specific identifier values, such as to convey a particular hardware or operating system configuration or other identifying information.

To answer the question if you can change this, I do not know of any configuration settings anywhere within android that let you change this. Based on the one you put in your question, it looks like android creates the VCI from the following:

`<dhcpcd and version>:<kernel and version>:<processor type>:<device board type>`

for the board type, you have herring, so if you opened up a shell and typed `getprop ro.product.board` I am willing to bet that the value that is output is "herring". Can I guess that you also have a Nexus S. I believe the Galaxy Nexus has a board named "tuna".